# Error with \includegraphics in TexStudio

Tags: includegraphics

```latex
\documentclass[ captions=tableheading, chapterprefix]{scrreprt} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}               % benötigt für Vektorgrafiken
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,compat/show suggested version=false} %aktuelle 
%Version ohne Meldung
\usepackage{float}                  % Befehel [H] nagelt Grafiken an eine 
%Position fest
\usepackage{pdfpages}               % Einbinden von PDF Dateien 

\usepackage{graphicx}               % Einbinden von Grafiken 
\graphicspath{{../Grafiken/}}       % Grafiken Pfad
\usepackage{color}                  %farbiger Text, Hintergrund etc



\begin{document}

Test
\begin{figure}

    \includegraphics{Kraftschlussellipse}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I got an error while using the package `includegraphics`. I read I should update TeXstudio and MikTeX, nothing changed. There is a preview of my picture when I have my mouse pointing on the code, the path must be correct. 
What is wrong with the code?

The entire `test.log` exceeds the 30000 characters. I hope I got the useful bit of it here:

```
l.21    \includegraphics{Kraftschlussellipse}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\Ginclude@graphics ...e \expandafter {\@curr@file 
                                                  }}\expandafter \filename@p...
l.21    \includegraphics{Kraftschlussellipse}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \unquote@name 

l.21    \includegraphics{Kraftschlussellipse}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \quote@name 

l.21    \includegraphics{Kraftschlussellipse}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \quote@name 

l.21    \includegraphics{Kraftschlussellipse}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


! LaTeX Error: File `Kraftschlussellipse' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.21    \includegraphics{Kraftschlussellipse}

I could not locate the file with any of these extensions:
.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

[1{C:/Users/student2/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please note that we generally keep it in English here as more people understands it.

Comment: Additionally please post the full log file for this mwe, not just the sniplet you provided (and not the parsed log file that texstudio gives you). You should be able to update your question and paste the log file into it.

Comment: You quite probably didn't update in user "and" admin mode.

Comment: Your mwe does not use pgfplots, float, pdfpages or color, so you can remove those, which will reduce the log to a degree where you should have no issues posting the entire log. From the full log we can often get hints on whether you have correctly updated your system

Comment: If the folder `Grafiken` is in the same folder of your main `.tex` file you should use `\graphicspath{{Grafiken/}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Ulrike was correct. I started the MiKTeXConsole with right click admin mode instead of starting it clicking switch to administrator mode. Thank you to all authors helping out quick!

**How to solve the problem**: Starting MiKTeX Console --> click on "switch to administrator mode" --> click update. 
Restart the console --> click on "stay in user mode" --> update